# No puedo agregar una imagen en html

Tags: html

Estoy empezando a aprender HTML y estoy tratando de insertar una imagen a como se explica en el curso pero no funciona, ya guarde la imagen en la carpeta servidor en el formato .jpg a como se explica pero al correr en Chrome solo me aparece el icono de imagen dañada.

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Pagina 1</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Bienvenidos a pagina 1<h1>

<img src="IMG_20180901_153721_764"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: agrega la extensión de la imagen, debe ser: `nombreImagen.jpg/png` depende el formato pero agregalo

Comment: cual el el nombre completo de tu imagen?

Comment: IMG_20180901_153721_764

Comment: no, despues de eso que extensión tiene? es jpg? es png? identifica la extensión y dime cual es

Comment: YA FUNCIONO~!! GEEENIOOO

Comment: Guarde la imagen sin extension osea solo su nombre dentro de la carpeta servidor IMG_20180901_153721_764 pero agregue la extension a como dijiste .jpg  en el codigo y funciono de maravilla!

Comment: sos un genio colega @shadow...

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo depende de como este tu servidor, seria bueno colocar mas información para poder ayudarte mejor
Suponiendo que tu archivo HTML y la imagen esta ubicado en la ruta "/"  del servidor es un simple y si una ruta de distinta podrias colocar la ruta completa

```html
<img src="IMG_20180901_153721_764.jpg"/>
```

aqui la url de una imagen
https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg 
y abajo como colocarla

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"/>
```

Comment: el error que por cierto ya se le resolvió solo fue que no puso la extensión de la imagen, solo eso